# Is well formed XML context-sensitive grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

> **Solution**
>
> Copy language is noncontracting, so it's context-sensitive. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar for transforming noncontracting grammar to explicitly $\alpha A \beta \rightarrow \alpha \gamma \beta$

Subj. I'm talking only about well-formed XML, i.e. all closing tags are correct.

Simplifying question: is `<name></name>` (where strings in opening and closing tags match) context-sensitive or unrestricted grammar?

I came out only to unrestricted grammar solution:

1. Expand to <name> < **StartReverse** eman **EndReverse** />
2. Reverse closing tag by pushing symbols one by one to the end

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is a language defined by SGML, which is a restricted form of context free grammar (essentially a [Dyck language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) with many types of parentesis). Such languages are (trivially) LL(1), thus very easy to parse.

Comment: Yes, but it does not verify document correctness on grammar level.

Comment: Also, Dyck language operates with finite set of parenthesis. Which is obvious to define for xml with limited length of node names. I'm interested in case with infinite set of parenthesis. In terms used in wiki, I want $\Sigma \in A^+$

Comment: @fal, XML doesn't have a infinite set of parentesis. And such an object would not be a language anymore (by the traditional definition, the alphabet is finite).

Comment: ok, I'll make it more simple. Let's restrict alphabet to `xy`. Let's define `L` as language `(Str)(Str)`, where `(Str)`s' are placeholders for **equal** strings. I found how to define it in unrestricted grammar. The question is how to define it in at least context-sensitive grammar, if it's possible at all.

Comment: @fal, a context-sensitive grammar for that is easy to build: Make $S \to (A)(B)$, $A)( \to x A )( X$, $X x \to x X$, $X y \to y X$, $X B \to x B$ and a similar set for adding $y$; to end make $A)( \to x x )(X'$, let $X'$ travel like $X$, but end with $X' B \to xx$ (and a slew of other nonterminals).

Comment: doesn't $Xx \rightarrow xX$ break context-sensitive grammar rules $\alpha A \beta \rightarrow \alpha \gamma \beta$?

Comment: @fal, "context sensitive" can be defined alternatively by length of LHS $\le$ length of RHS in all productions. Both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: awesome, thanks, I've finally got this. I overlooked that fact. BTW, turns out my 'unrestricted grammar solution' is actually context-sensitive.

Comment: @vonbrand I just read [this paper](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy561/Data/Papers/formalPropertiesXMLgrammars.pdf). According to what I understand, it is the schema/DTD that allows an XML to be validated and enumerates the set of opening and closing tags. Since XML is not necessarily always validated against a schema, and, thus, the set of opening and closing tags may not be finite, the set of valid opening and closing tags must be constructed from context. I have a hunch that XML is context-sensitive without a DTD -- or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @vonbrand The conclusion that XML is context free does not seem right. In particular, A language `{wXw} | w,x \in {0,1}*` or even `{ww} | w \in{0,1}*`  is in the family of scattered context languages. See [Greibach 1969](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000069800152). It is not a dyck language because the parentheses used are not finite. It can be context free only if the parenthesis can be enumerated.

Comment: Here, by parenthesis I mean closing and ending tags. There can be an infinite number of closing and ending tags `<xxx> and </xxx>`.